# Javascript clearInterval will not clear

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clearInterval after when my _i is equal = 10.

```
var intervalFunction = function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    chart.draw((_i++/10).toFixed(1));
    if(Math.round(_i) == 10){
      clearInterval(intervalFunction);
    }
  },100)
}
intervalFunction();
```

Comment: Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) for an example on how to use `clearInterval`. Why do you think you have to pass the function to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `clearInterval()` function expects the return value of a previous `setInterval()` call to be passed, i.e.:

```
var iid = setInterval(function() {
    // do your stuff
    clearInterval(iid);
}, 100);
```

This is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval):

> Cancels repeated action which was set up using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter passed to [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) should be the value that was returned from the initial call, not the function doing the call

```
var _i = 0;

function intervalFunction() {
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    chart.draw((_i++/10).toFixed(1));
    if(Math.round(_i) == 10){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  },100)
}
```